# Loosing payload data on raw socket, winSock2

Tags: c++, windows, winsock2, raw-sockets

Im trying to handle raw sockets as follow :
**Sender** : sends UDP packets on several sockets to receiver through a switch
**Receiver**: receives the data and store it

On the switch I configure one of the switch ports as mirror port, and I connect a PC with
another software to listen to the mirror port.

On the PC there is a software that using raw sockets to get and handle the mirrored traffic.
When using Wireshark on the PC I see all the mirrored traffic as expected.

Now I'm running the raw socket implementation ( standard, I have downloaded an example, I added a link at the end of the text )
The application gets the UDP traffic and Im able to filter only the traffic I need (i.e. ip and port).

The problem is that the method `rcvfrom` returns only up to 1500 bytes, even when the data is
larger then that (2080 bytes for that matter).
My question is how do I configure the raw socket to get the full data (MTU issue ?)
I used the exact code as [described here](https://www.programmersought.com/article/86124450240/) (only changed IP and ports)
Thanks.

Comment: _If you look at the IP header, is the packet fragmented? Or checking the Ethernet header, is it using [jumbo frames](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jumbo_frame)?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes, as I see in Wireshark, it is fragmented.

Comment: Then you need to read all fragments and reassemble them into a single packet.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Can you please point me to such an example? (Or post an example as an answer)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks I figured it out :)